# Proving that Direct product $G_1 \times ... \times G_n$ is abelian if and only if each of $G_1, ...,G_n$ is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If we let $G_1,...,G_n$ be groups,

how can we prove that the direct product $G_1 \times .... \times G_n$ is abelian if and only if each of $G_1,...,G_n$ is abelian.

Please if someone can help and guide with this question...

Answer (score 7):

Keep in mind that two elements of $G_1 \times .... \times G_n$ are equal if and only if all of their components are equal, and that the operation  on $G_1 \times .... \times G_n$ is made componentwise.

So $(a_1, \dots, a_n) \cdot (b_1, \dots, b_n) = (b_1, \dots, b_n)  \cdot (a_1, \dots, a_n)$ if and only if...

Comment: Thankx a lot for your guidance and help..

Comment: @DenishSen, you're welcome!

Comment: Do we have to complete our proof by saying that the inverse and unit elements exists ...I mean if we write if and only if the element (e, e) is a unit element since for any (a,b) Ɛ G1,…….Gn holds that (a,b).(e,e) = (a.e, b.e) = (a, b) and similarly (e,e)(a,b) = (a,b).
The inverse of typical element (a, b) Ɛ G1 x …….Gn is (a-1, b-1) since by definition, (a,b) . (a-1, b-1) = (a.a-1, b.b-1) = (e, e) and similarly ,
(a-1, b-1). (a,b) = (e,

Comment: @DenishSen, it depends on the assignment. From your formulation, it appears that the construction of the direct product is already assumed. In any case, the proofs you mention are indeed done componentwise.

Answer (score 4):

The forward direction should be clear. For the reverse direction, suppose there is some $G_i$ which is not abelian, meaning that there are $a,b\in G_i$ such that $ab\neq ba.$

Now consider $xy$ and $yx$ where $x= (1,1,\cdots, a, \cdots, 1), y= (1,1,\cdots, b, \cdots, 1) \in G_1 \times G_2 \cdots \times G_n$. What does this say about the abelian-ness of the direct product?

Comment: Why so indirect? You can prove it directly.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Ahh that's true. For some reason this was how I thought of it first, but now that you point it out, the direct proof is more natural.

Comment: Thank you Sir for the help...