# In direct products of $n$ groups, do we also prove conditions for a group to be abelian or not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

If we let $G_1,...,G_n$ be groups,

When proving that the direct product $G_1 \times .... \times G_n$ is abelian if and only if each of $G_1,...,G_n$ is abelian, can someone please help me Im concerned about whether it should also prove that it holds for the conditions of a group to be abelian(inverse, unit element ...) or just prove straightforward that left hand side is true iff right hand side is?

Can someone please help clarify this. Thanks

Comment: You can see this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292004/proving-that-direct-product-g-1-times-times-g-n-is-abelian-if-and-only-i?rq=1

Comment: Thank you Seirios, I have seen this question but is still not so clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts that you need to prove, as follows (in either order).

First, assume that the direct product $G_{1}\times\cdots\times G_{n}$ is abelian, and then show that each of $G_{1},\ldots, G_{n}$ must also be abelian.  (Hint: Find a homomorphism from the direct product **onto** an arbitrary $G_{i}$ and use that to help with the proof.)

Second, assume that all of $G_{1},\ldots, G_{n}$ are abelian, and show that the direct product $G_{1}\times\cdots\times G_{n}$ must be abelian.  (Hint: Just use the definitions.  What does a typical element of $G_{1}\times\cdots\times G_{n}$ look like?)

Comment: for the first part also just working with the definitions work. This is just to clarify that there is nothing fancy needed for either parts.

Comment: Agreed.  I just have this penchant for trying to get students to think with homomorphisms. :-)

Comment: Thank you both for your feedback.

Comment: Great, so its just using the definitions for the direct products of $n$ groups and not prove the axioms for a group to be abelian. Right. Cheers.